# Will the D-Link GO-USB-N150 Wireless N 150 Easy USB Adapter work without problems in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, usb

My ten year old XP pc has a D-Link GO-USB-N150 Wireless N 150 Easy USB Adapter. Will this usb wifi adapter work well with Ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Your question, as is, is difficult to understand. Please, restate it.

Answer (score 1):

### Booting Linux

Ubuntu can be sort of memory intensive for an old pc.  The first step is to make sure you have at least 512 mb of ram.  For other requirements check here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements.  The good news about an old pc is that most of the hardware should be figured out.  However, there is a chance that you may need to rely on some legacy drivers for things like graphics.  I would recommend against installing ubuntu desktop.  Look at lubunuhttp://www.lubuntu.net/ and xubntu: http://xubuntu.org/ as they are FAR less processor/memory intensive.

However, I would recommend that you look into something more lightweight like archbang http://archbang.org/.

What you might want to try first is see how your computer handles one of the light live distros such as slitaz which only requires 16mb of ram: http://www.slitaz.org/en/.

You can burn any of these options onto a cd as per the distro specific instructions.

Now, as actually installing/booting a cd, you are going to need to edit your bios.  This depends on your computer but the process is usually similar.

The ubuntu wiki has a guide for this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD The process is the same for most distros.

### Installing

Here you need to choose if you want to keep xp.  If not any installer will have the option to wipe your hard drive and just install linux.  However, if you want to keep xp your are going to need to partition your drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition

### Wireless

As far as the adapter you are using, you should check out this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2013323

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter SHOULD work with Ubuntu but you might have to blacklist rt2800usb by opening a terminal and type in
`gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` 
This will open up a text file.
Then you have to go to the bottom of the text and add the line **blacklist rt2800usb** Then you just have to save and exit the file and terminal.

If you still don't have Internet access after this you can try to open your router settings(If you don't know what this is get someone else to do it for you) And set the wireless mode to **802.11n & 802.11g & 802.11b**